# ASP.net gridview sorting with linq result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

up till now I have a linq query that fills a datagrid perfectly with filterconditions.
however, when I try to implement sorting I fail.

I have the following code behind. it catches the start of the sort.

```
protected void gvServers_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        SortDataAsc(e.SortExpression);
    }
    else if (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
        SortDataDesc(e.SortExpression);
    }
}
```

in these submethods I'd want to hendle the sorting of each possible sorting expression.
however, when I try to use the data that is already in the gridview it won't allow me to linq it with an orderby

```
private void SortDataAsc(string p)
{
    var data = gvServers.DataSource;
    switch (p)
    {
        case "domain":
            var sorted = data.nothinghappenshere
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

as you can see pointing to the nothinghappenshere I cannot sort the data (proabaly because it's a var).

What I've read online is that you can just get the data from the gridview as I try to do in SortDataAsc(), but it doesn't seem to work that way.

I simply want to order by a certain field in my resultset (which is in this case an anonymous class derived from a join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's because `DataSource` is weakly typed.

If you cast it to `IEnumerable<YourDataType>` it should be fine. However, note that `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` don't sort in place - you'd have to order the data and then reassign the `DataSource`.

You say that your data type as an anonymous type - you'll have to change that, I'm afraid. Anonymous types can only (easily) be used in a strongly typed way in single method - you can't  specify the name later on, so you can't refer to the same properties etc.

It's not terribly hard to convert an anonymous type into a named one though. [Here's an answer giving an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964334/how-do-i-declare-a-field-with-anonymous-type-c/964341#964341)

Comment: as I mentioned above, there is no datatype to type it with. the results are a join in which I used the select new {} to get everything I need ...

Comment: Sorry, was busy editing. Will try to find the anonymous type question.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but at the time it seemd overkill to make a type for that purpose.

I suppose it's the only way out to be able to sort ...

Comment: It's the only way to sort without using reflection of some kind, yes. (Well, there *are* grotty hack ways to effectively reuse an anonymous type, but they're horrible and I wouldn't recommend them.)

Comment: the link you gave me suggests I make a default constructor with all properties, I would thinnk this isn't necesarry when using object initializers ...

Comment: If you don't mind it being mutable, that would work. That answer was meant to be creating a directly equivalent type, that's all.