# Get DataSet in RowCommand event/Get modified rows in RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the dataset in `RowCommand` event. Like this:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)(gvImages.DataSource);
DataTable dtChanges =  dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

But my dataTable returns `NULL`.

Can any one help me find the modified rows in the `RowCommand` event?

Comment: How are you updating your DataSet using your GridView control? Are you using any type of data source controls like SqlDataSource etc.

Answer (score 2):

Store the Datatable in the Session or ViewState. Retrieve it and modify it based on user selected row and change then save back to session. On the Rowcommand you will be able to retrieve the changes because they will be stored in the session/viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979724/asp-net-gridview-datasource-null-when-sorting).  Basically, the underlying datasource used by a GridView is not saved in the view state, which means it is unavailable during a post back.  If you need access to the data source, you must cache it yourself.